# Ошибка в парсере python

Tags: python, парсер

Вот код:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def get_all_links(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    text = soup.find('div', class_='pagination-pages').find_all('a', class_='pagination-page')
    print(text.prettyfy())
def main():
    url = 'https://www.avito.ru'
    get_all_links(( get_html(url) ))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

И сама ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PythonProject\mywork.py", line 19, in <module>
     main()
  File "C:\PythonProject\mywork.py", line 14, in main
     get_all_links(( get_html(url) ))
  File "C:\PythonProject\mywork.py", line 10, in get_all_links
     text = soup.find('div', class_='pagination-pages').find_all('a', class_='pagination-page')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
[Finished in 0.9s]
```

[image: Скриншот окна редактора с ошибкой]

Answer (score 1):

Заверните место возникновения ошибки в try-except, добавьте вывод содержимого полученной страницы и убедитесь, что в нём присутствуют элементы удовлетворяющие селектору

```
try:
    text = (soup.find('div', class_='pagination-pages')
                .find_all('a', class_='pagination-page'))
except AttributeError:
    print(html)
```

Скорее всего, Avito замечает парсинг и начинает выдавать вам заглушку.