# Парсер не находит нужные данные на странице

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Есть код, который должен находить информацию на странице сайта по id:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bS

# это работает
amazon_de = 'https://www.amazon.de/Sony-Digitalkamera-Touch-Display-Vollformatsensor-Kartenslots/dp/B07B4R8QGM/ref=sr_1_3?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&keywords=sony+alpha+ilce-7m3&qid=1562051561&s=gateway&sr=8-3'.replace(' ', '')

# это нет
amazon_com = 'https://www.amazon.com/AmazonBasics-1000-Gigabit-Ethernet-Adapter/dp/B00M77HMU0/ref=sr_1_7?fst=as%3Aoff&pf_rd_i=16225007011&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_p=74069509-93ef-4a3c-8dca-a9e3fa773a64&pf_rd_r=9W8S7N7S7SPKZEHEATYP&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-4&pf_rd_t=101&qid=1562052237&rnid=16225007011&s=computers-intl-ship&sr=1-7&th=1'.replace(' ', '')


headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Ваш User-Agent"
}

def get_data(link: str, ua: dict,  title_id: str, cost_id: str) -> dict:
    page = requests.get(link, headers=ua)
    data = bS(page.content, 'html.parser')

    title = data.find(id=cost_id).get_text()
    price = data.find(id=title_id).get_text()

    return {"title": title, "price": price}


print(get_data(amazon_de, headers, 'productTitle', 'price_inside_buybox'))

print(get_data(amazon_com, headers, 'productTitle', 'priceblock_ourprice'))
```

И я не понимаю, по какой причине это происходит, если на сайте есть все теги с нужными id.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка в парсере python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/845830/204271)

Comment: Я не про ошибку, исключение возникает в том случае, если поиск возвращает None, но именно в этом то и дело, почему он возвращает None, если все теги и их параметры есть. Но я так понял, что и правда сайт замечает парсинг.

Comment: В ответе по ссылке есть возможное объяснение этому - в момент вызова `get_data` содержимое `page.content` может не соответствовать тому, что вы видите в бразуере. Если вы видите в консоль полученные данные в момент возникновения проблемы, то сможете выяснить соответствует ли это действительности в вашем случае.

Comment: Проверьте статус запроса, он должен быть 200 для успешного выполнения (r.status_code), но скорее всего статус будет 503 или что-то в этом духе